# Adding variable to python result

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
from random import randint

while True:
    list1 = []
    list2 = []
    zero = 0
    one = 0
    sec = int(input("Enter a number seconds : "))
    if sec < 0 or sec == 0:
        break
    random = randint(0, 2 ** sec - 1)
    bin_key_one = f'{random:0{int(sec)}b}'
    for x in bin_key_one:
        list1.append(x)
    for i in list1:
        if i == '0':
            zero = zero + 1
        elif i == '1':
            one = one + 1
    if zero - one < 0:
        list2.append("backward")
    elif zero - one > 0:
        list2.append("forward")
    elif zero - one == 0:
        list2.append("No moves")

    print("The Final position  ", zero - one, list2, "steps", end=" ")
    print("The random number = ", random, end=" ")
    print("to binary = ", bin_key_one)
    list1 = []
    list2 = []
    zero = 0
    one = 0
```

I need to keep the result of `zero - one` in result but when I put them in result the result come `0` every time I need to add a variable to make it work.

Comment: What's becoming 0?

Comment: @Carcigenicate when I add variable contain the sum of zero - one

Comment: Hi Abuerr, welcome to SO. Please edit your question to make clarifications, not use the comments section alone for that. (This will help you get more useful answers.)

Answer (score 0):

With 'keep the result of zero-one' I guess you mean the values you put in list2. In that case you need to put list2 outside the loop:

```
from random import randint

list2 = []

while True:
    list1 = []
    zero = 0
    one = 0
    sec = int(input("Enter a number seconds : "))
    if sec < 0 or sec == 0:
        break
    random = randint(0, 2 ** sec - 1)
    bin_key_one = f'{random:0{int(sec)}b}'
    for x in bin_key_one:
        list1.append(x)
    for i in list1:
        if i == '0':
            zero = zero + 1
        elif i == '1':
            one = one + 1
    if zero - one < 0:
        list2.append("backward")
    elif zero - one > 0:
        list2.append("forward")
    elif zero - one == 0:
        list2.append("No moves")6

    print("The Final position  ", zero - one, list2, "steps", end=" ")
    print("The random number = ", random, end=" ")
    print("to binary = ", bin_key_one)

for i in list2:
    print(i)
```

This is the result

```
Enter a number seconds : 6
The Final position   0 ['No moves'] steps The random number =  28 to binary =  011100
Enter a number seconds : 4
The Final position   2 ['No moves', 'forward'] steps The random number =  8 to binary =  1000
Enter a number seconds : 2
The Final position   0 ['No moves', 'forward', 'No moves'] steps The random number =  1 to binary =  01
Enter a number seconds : 0
No moves
forward
No moves
```